# Including a Module in a Controller when using a different folder structure for the Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a controller in:

```
app/controllers/admin/account/users_controller.rb
```

And my model in:

```
app/models/account/user.rb
```

The desired table name is "account_users".

If I run:

```
rails g scaffold account/user username:string
```

Then the scaffold generates the files correctly, and everything works.  I now put my controller and view user files into an admin folder (I'm omitting the view, since the problem is related to the controller and model):

```
scaffold generated: app/controllers/account/users_controller.rb 
relocated: app/controllers/admin/account/users_controller.rb
```

In the controller I have to modify the following:

```
scaffold generated:  class Account::UsersController < ApplicationController
modified:  class Admin::Account::UsersController < ApplicationController
```

I changed my routes to:

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :account do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

So far so good, everything works when I go to localhost:3000/admin/account/users

I'm trying to DRY up my controller now, every database call is prefixed with the "Account::" module. It looks something like this:

```
class Admin::Account::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @account_users = Account::User.all
  end
```

When I change the controller to:

```
class Admin::Account::UsersController < ApplicationController

  include Account

  def index
    @account_users = User.all
  end
```

I get an error saying that the "User" is an uninitialized constant.  My first thought is that the Account Module is not being found.  My Account Module looks like this (app/models/account.rb):

```
module Account
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'account_'
  end
end
```

I wrote some debug code inside this Module, and it is executing, so it does look like the Account module is being included in the controller.

I'm thinking that the controller is not recognizing the "account_" prefix, and thinks that when I call User.all, it literally is looking for a users table instead of an account_users table.

So my question is, does anyone know if you can include a module in a controller when using a different folder structure for the model and controller?

I'm using Rails 4.0 and Ruby 2.0.0.  Thanks if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add this to line 1 of the controller

```
require 'account/user'
class Admin::Account::UsersController < ApplicationController

  include Account

  def index
    @account_users = User.all
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

1-

You want your user model to be named `User` instead of the generated `Account::User`, you need to:

- replace in your controller and in all other files `Account::User` by `User`
- replace in your user model `class Account::User < ActiveRecord::Base` by `class User < ActiveRecord::Base`
- move your user model file from app/models/account/user.rb to app/models/user.rb
- restart your server/guard/zeus/console/etc... , this may be not necessary but sometime changes are not picked up and lead to weird problems

**EDIT:** Your class names must correspond to the directory structure: `User` model must be located in file models/user.rb; `Account::User` model model must be located in file models/account/user.rb, if you do not follow this convention you will have a uninitialized constant error and that's what append to you.

2-

You are using `table_name_prefix`, which is a model method, not a controller method. So your module `Account` must not be included in your `UsersController` controller but in your `User` model instead.

**EDIT** There is no doubt `table_name_prefix` is not a controller method, its a model method. So you must place it in your model in a way or another, is you really want to use a module see my point 3. But I suspect that your module contains controllers methods, in this case move `table_name_prefix` out of your module directly into your model

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/table_name_prefix/class

3-

I doubt your module `Account` is correctly written, so if your table_prefix is still not seen by rails after doing all that, try to modify your module `Account` like so:

```
module Account

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def table_name_prefix
      'account_'
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Regarding step #1, I want to have my model in app/models/account/user.rb instead of app/models/user.rb.  Sorry, I think I need to re-ask this question in small steps since it's getting a bit complicated.  Regarding step #2, including a module seems to work in the controller when generating the scaffold but not when the controller and model are in different folder structures.

Comment: Edited my answer to give you more information on how Rails work. Sorry if you did not expect that but you are trying to do impossible things and that why you have those problems. My answer intends to explain you how to do thing 'the Rails way', and in this case there is no other way. My advises are correct and will fix your problems. Read them, follow my lead and you'll be be fixed :) Good luck