# How does including a module work inside a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I do:

```
rails generate scaffold account/user username
```

I get a controller that looks like this:

```
class Account::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @account_users = Account::User.all
  end
...
end
```

If I include the Account Module, then it looks like all the database calls don't need to be prefixed with "Account::".  I.e.

```
class Account::UsersController < ApplicationController

  include Account

  def index
    @account_users = User.all #this works because I included the Account Module above
  end
...
end
```

Now if I were to move my

controllers/account/users_controller.rb

file to:

controllers/**admin**/account/users_controller.rb

The file looks like this (note: I also corrected my routes file after this move):

```
class Admin::Account::UsersController < ApplicationController

  include Account

  def index
    @account_users = User.all #this call does not work now
  end
...
end
```

But I get an error saying "uninitialized constant Admin::Account::UsersController::User"

It looks like rails is trying to make a database call on the "User" model without the "Account::" module in front of it.

So how does including modules in controllers work?  Why does this not work when I move my controller into a different file (and leave the model in the same location from the generated scaffold) but it works with the scaffold generated files?  How can I fix this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including a Module in a Controller when using a different folder structure for the Model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026421/including-a-module-in-a-controller-when-using-a-different-folder-structure-for-t)

Comment: I already provided you with a full answer in your other duplicate question. You cannot have a `::User` model located in models/account/user.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I didn't realize you can just explicitly require the path to the module you would like to include.  I learned this after reading up on modules some more...

So adding an explicit call to "require 'account/user'" just outside the controller class makes it so including the module in the controller works.

Answer (score 0):

Resolving the name of a module is done relative to the current module. Try and change it to:

```
include ::Account
```

or

```
include ::Admin::Account
```

(depending on the module in which your User model is defined)

This will tell ruby to look in the global namespace for the module `Account`

Comment: Where is your User model defined? is it in `::Admin::Account` ? if so you should include it.

Comment: I have my User model defined in "models/account/user.rb".  Basically I want the model to stay in the same spot as the scaffold generated but the controller in a different location than the scaffold generated. That way I can have multiple controllers/namespaces referencing the same models.

Comment: it must be a very special case for you to want to hide your user model under some namespace. you also need to have quite extensive knowledge of how rails works with such models. are you sure this is the case? if not - just take user model out into models/ and be done with it.

Comment: Yeah I have multiple websites that I plan on running with the same RoR install.  I'll have multiple namespaces/controllers for different websites that all share the same models.